# How to Fix CWE-470: Use of Externally-Controlled Input to Select Classes or Code ('Unsafe Reflection')

Tags: java, reflection, veracode

I got a 470 on a line in my code and rightfully so as defined by Vera.

Vera says to fix:

> Apply strict input validation by using whitelists or indirect
>   selection to ensure that the user is only selecting allowable classes
>   or code.

So I created a strict whitelist of what class name reflection can have access to as a `Set<String>`

I then wrapped the `Class.forName` in an

```
if (whitelist.contains(className) {
   Veracode still fires in here with a 470
}
```

Anyone know what the fix has to look like for Vera not to fire? I feel I have followed their recommended remediation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to resolve it using sanitizer class/method that get className validate and return value from String from hard coded value - for example:

public class MySanitizer {

```
public static String sanitizeClassName(final String className) throws MyException {

    if(!className.equals("com.my.MyClass")) 
        throw new MyException("Class not valid: "  + className);

    return "com.my.MyClass";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that all class names must come from a trusted source.
The only trusted source is a hard-coded string in a class file.
Nothing read from properties files, no collection you create and pass into a validation mechanism.

It must see a hard-coded constant "com.dang.this.is.strict.ClassName:" being loaded.
Hard-coded whitelist of strings.

You can have some great validation code to make sure nothing bad is going on, but it will not pass, since not hard coded string.  In this situation you mitigate and provide the explanation and hope that it is sufficient for the person(s) reviewing the results.

They do say

> Apply strict input validation by using whitelists or indirect
>   selection to ensure that the user is only selecting allowable classes
>   or code.

I just didn't realize whitelists were strictly string constants in classes.  My mistake was thinking I could build the whitelist in code at run-time.  Which sometimes I need to do, so I will be keeping my validator and claim mitigation.